# Windows 2008 keeps restarting itself

Tags: windows-server-2008

Windows server 2008 SP1 keeps retstarting itself after the ctrl+alt+del screen.

I have to quickly watch the screen and login within a minute. Even if I miss a second, it restarts.

But, once I login, it stays calm.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it a graceful reboot or a sudden / blue screen style reboot? Does the same happen in safe mode?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the logs, there's bound to be some tell-tale line in there.